# read/write to large array using large loop - execution time concerns

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, optimization, heap-memory

So recently I ran into a problem that I thought was interesting and I couldn't fully explain. I've highlighted the nature of the problem in the following code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <chrono> 
#include <iostream> 

#define NLOOPS 10

void doWorkFast(int total, int *write, int *read)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < NLOOPS; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            write[i] = read[i] + i;
        }
    }
}

void doWorkSlow(int total, int *write, int *read, int innerLoopSize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NLOOPS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < total/innerLoopSize; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < innerLoopSize; k++) {
                write[j*k + k] = read[j*k + k] + j*k + k;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = 1000000000;
    
    int *heapMemoryWrite = new int[n];
    int *heapMemoryRead = new int[n];
    

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        heapMemoryRead[i] = 1;
    }

    std::memset(heapMemoryWrite, 0, n * sizeof(int));   

    auto start1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    doWorkFast(n,heapMemoryWrite, heapMemoryRead);
    

    auto finish1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();  
    auto duration1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(finish1 - start1); 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        heapMemoryRead[i] = 1;
    }

    std::memset(heapMemoryWrite, 0, n * sizeof(int));

    auto start2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    doWorkSlow(n,heapMemoryWrite, heapMemoryRead, 10);


    auto finish2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();  
    auto duration2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(finish2 - start2); 

    std::cout << "Small inner loop:" << duration1.count() << " microseconds.\n" << 
                 "Large inner loop:" << duration2.count() << " microseconds." << std::endl; 

    delete[] heapMemoryWrite;
    delete[] heapMemoryRead;
}
```

Looking at the two doWork* functions, for every iteration, we are reading the same addresses adding the same value and writing to the same addresses. I understand that in the `doWorkSlow` implementation, we are doing one or two more operations to resolve `j*k + k`, however, I think it's reasonably safe to assume that relative to the time it takes to do the load/stores for memory read and write, the time contribution of these operations is negligible.

Nevertheless, `doWorkSlow` takes about twice as long (46.8s) compared to `doWorkFast` (25.5s) on my i7-3700 using `g++ --version` 7.5.0. While things like cache prefetching and branch prediction come to mind, I don't have a great explanation as to why `doWorkFast` is much faster than `doWorkSlow`. Does anyone have insight?

Thanks

Comment: What are your compile flags?

Comment: I'm not using any flags, though when I compiled with -o3 -o2 and -o1 I had similar results (i.e. slow takes ~2x).

Comment: My guess is that the difference comes from the array accesses, `doWorkFast` accesses the array elements one after another (increment by 1), but `doWorkSlow` increments the indexes by `j+1`, which makes cache prefeteching more difficult.

Comment: Without optimizations, you could be looking at calculating `total/innerLoopSize` every iteration.  The same goes for `j*k+k`.   Try calculating `j*k+k` once and store in a temporary (constant) variable, before the `write` statement, e.g. `const int index = j * k + k; write[index] = ...;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looking at the two doWork* functions, for every iteration, we are reading the same addresses adding the same value and writing to the same addresses.

This is not true!

In `doWorkFast`, you index each integer incrementally, as `array[i]`.

```
array[0]
array[1]
array[2]
array[3]
```

In `doWorkSlow`, you index each integer as `array[j*k + k]`, which jumps around and repeats.

When `j` is 10, for example, and you iterate `k` from 0 onwards, you are accessing

```
array[0]    // 10*0+0
array[11]   // 10*1+1
array[22]   // 10*2+2
array[33]   // 10*3+3
```

This will prevent your optimizer from using instructions that can operate on many adjacent integers at once.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for pointing this out. In this example, coding the indices this way was an implementation flaw (should have been `j*innerLoopSize + k`, however, in when resolving the issue, I saw that the execution times were similar. The main lesson I see, though, is that we should be doing contiguous memory accesses when possible though to make use of SIMD?